# remove duplicates SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table:

```
╔════╤════════════╗
║ id │ date       ║
╠════╪════════════╣
║ 1  │ 2001-08-01 ║
╟────┼────────────╢
║ 1  │ 2001-09-02 ║
╟────┼────────────╢
║ 1  │ 2001-09-02 ║
╟────┼────────────╢
║ 1  │ 2001-09-01 ║
╟────┼────────────╢
║ 2  │ 2000-01-01 ║
╟────┼────────────╢
║ 3  │ 2000-09-01 ║
╚════╧════════════╝
```

and want to receive a max date using code:

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM data tt
inner join(
SELECT id, max(data) as lastDate
FROM data
GROUP BY id) groupedtt
ON tt.id = groupedtt.id AND tt.data = groupedtt.lastDate
```

but via this code i get duplicate values like

```
╔════╤════════════╗
║ id │ date       ║
╠════╪════════════╣
║ 1  │ 2001-09-02 ║
╟────┼────────────╢
║ 1  │ 2001-09-02 ║
╟────┼────────────╢
║ 2  │ 2000-01-01 ║
╟────┼────────────╢
║ 3  │ 2000-09-01 ║
╚════╧════════════╝
```

what should i change to get table without dupliates like this:

```
╔════╤════════════╗
║ id │ date       ║
╠════╪════════════╣
║ 1  │ 2001-09-02 ║
╟────┼────────────╢
║ 2  │ 2000-01-01 ║
╟────┼────────────╢
║ 3  │ 2000-09-01 ║
╚════╧════════════╝
```

i'm using ms sql server

Comment: Simply `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: or `GROUP BY id` int the main query

Comment: @jarlh but why use `JOIN` in the first place?

Comment: No @jarlh that won't work here. The OP needs to get the maximum date for each id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` if you want the whole row:

```
select tt.*
from (select tt.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by data desc) as seqnum
      from data tt
     ) tt
where seqnum = 1;
```

I'm guessing there are other fields you want from the row, because your subquery does exactly what you specify that you want.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the query you are using to join your original table:

```
SELECT id, max(date) as [date]
FROM data
GROUP BY id;
```